# How to read CPU,RAM or Other hardware properties in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: java, android, manifest, aapt

Hello i need to read Phone Hardware Properties in apk. 
Is there any aapt command or java project for this?
I am using `aapt -l a game.apk` and there is no hardware property at there.

If Game Developer add hardware properties in AndroidManifest.xml how can i read ?

Comment: you cant read in manifest file bt can read in activiy class file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In google play we can discover Device Properties;

- API Levels
- Version Name
- Version Code
- Sdk Version

[More Info: Support Device](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/index.html)